# HTML element type in CSS class and ID selectors

Tags: html, css

For an HTML element like this:

```
<div class="cas"></div>
```

...can you use an element before the CSS, like this:

```
div.cas {
}
```

...or like this?:

```
.cas {
}
```

Or either way?

Comment: Actually, a better duplicate is [How do I select an element that has a certain class?](//stackoverflow.com/q/16946878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, either way, depending on your context.

`div.cas` selects any `<div>` element with class "cas".
`.cas` selects *any type* of element with the class "cas".

For example:

```css
.test1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
p.test1 {
  color: white;
}

div.test2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
p.test2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">DIV TEST1</div>
<p class="test1">P TEST1</p>
<div class="test2">DIV TEST2</div>
<p class="test2">P TEST2</p>
```

See [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Comment: Thanks I was wondering if you were allowed to do that

Answer (score 0):

Using the class selector will select that element, and others with the same class.

Adding the tag to the selection (div.cas) will only select divs with that class.

Both will work, so either.